# Removing unused Zend libraries from Magento

Tags: zend-framework

I'm overriding a Magento 1.9 clean directory with a 5 years customized store.
That store was patched and updated many times since Magento 1.3.

Database was manually fixed and all store works as expected after upgrade.

But I saw many abandoned Zend files in diff process.

```
lib/Zend/InfoCard.php
lib/Zend/Cloud/StorageService/Adapter/Nirvanix.php
lib/Zend/Http/UserAgent/Features/Adapter/WurflApi.php
lib/Zend/Locale/Data/(many xml files - ldml nodes)
lib/Zend/Markup/Parser/Textile.php
```

I don't know if this is a required Zend library anymore.

Can I remove that files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a project for ZF1 that allows you to pick the packages you want and build a Zend library from that: http://epic.codeutopia.net/pack/

Now for which classes you do or do not need, that's a bit more tricky. Eeven within ZF there are probably several cross dependencies so next to finding out what Magento is using you'll also need to keep an eye on that.

One tool that can help you with that is http://phpxref.sourceforge.net/. I've never used it myself but from what I've heard it works quite ok, although the last time I heard about it was about 4 years ago I think.

At the end of the day it comes down to effort vs. gain. And to be honest, I'm not sure it's worth the effort to remove the classes. For example, future patches for Magento 1.x might use that library after all or a 3rd party module might depend on it.

On the other side, if they're not in the current Magento installation it's reasonable to assume they're unused for your installation as well.

**tl;dr / conclussion**

set up a dev environment and give it a try. Check logs etc for errors and warnings and if it checks out go ahead and deploy it live